# electrum wallet console - how to get help on a command

Tags: electrum, electrum-console

I'm trying to use the electrum wallet console to get help on a command.
I can do `help()` or any other command
but i cannot do `help <some command>`
cannot find documentation about the wallet console

Of course i can do from my terminal `electrum help <some command>`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no way to get documentation from inside the Console itself. However, you can browse the source code:

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/lib/commands.py

Alternatively, this article lists all built-in functions, their arguments, and provides many examples of use/output:

https://bitzuma.com/posts/an-introduction-to-the-electrum-python-console/

Answer (score 0):

To see the list of Electrum commands you type:

```
electrum help
```

To see the documentation for a command you type:

```
electrum help <command>
```

The link to the Electrum documentation is here:
http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/cmdline.html

Comment: The question was on the Console tab of the GUI client, not the commandline tool